# Adding an image to a container background using css

Tags: css, background, containers

First I have my container.

```
 .container {
    width: 780px;
    background: #FFF;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Then I add this with the goal of having the image display across the container and spanning the 780px. The image will fade to pure black at the bottom and it will then mix with the background color.

```
.container {
        width: 780px;
        background: #FFF url(picture.png) no-repeat center top;
        margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Nothing happens when I do this, it does work when I do something similar to my site background through "body".

Thanks for the help.

Edit: The more I think about it, do I have to do this through HTML, is there a way to make an image inserted in the html fall behind everything else and not be able to be interacted with?

Edit 2: With the help from the first 2 answer I am at this:

```
.container {
    width: 780px;
    background: url(Portfolio Assets/PortfolioUnderNavbg.png) no-repeat center top #000;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100%; 
}
```

But it still won't work, I forgot to mention that the page does have a header, so I think I have to somehow make the background image move down to be under the header but still in the container. I read that background only accepts percentage adjustments in height but that was older documentation. Is there a way to make it start at say, 100px down from the top of the container?

Comment: jsfildde it to make it easier to see what you are talking about.

Comment: Is the missing closing curly brace a typo, or the reason you're having trouble?  You can do this with CSS, that's what `background` is for.

Comment: Sorry, I just didn't copy it. I will fix it right now.

Answer (score 4):

Change to `background:url('your-image.png') no-repeat center top #FFF`

What's happening is the #FFF color code is overriding the image url.

[Some docs.](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/colors.html#background-properties)

Comment: I changed it to this and it still wont show the image, which is so weird because literally 20 lines up I have the exact same thing for the background of the entire page and it works perfect.

Comment: I think something is messed up somewhere else. As another commenter mentioned, a jsFiddle would be helpful.  Also, try adding `display:block;` to the .container

Answer (score 2):

```
   .container 
    {
        width: 780px;
        background: #FFF url(picture.jpg) no-repeat center top;
        margin: 0 auto;
        height:100%;
   }
```

i think .... u give height:100%; like above code

Answer (score 0):

.container 
    {
        width: 780px;
        background: #FFF url('picture.jpg') no-repeat center top;
        margin: 0 auto;
        height:'your-img-size';
   }

i guess it's working...

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean. This is what I had the first time and didn't work.

Comment: pay attention... you need to set the "height" of your container class.
if this fails, try to change the background: #FFF, cause sometime the color may "erase" the img;

Comment: I have Height: 100% because the container should scale with the length of the content. I will try a few different color codes and see what happens.